# Error: Infra Phase complete, 0/0 resources updated in 02 seconds

Tags: apache-flex, chef-infra, chef-workstation

I am trying to create a file cookbook, but it does not create a file for me. I am getting this once I run the command:

[root@ip-172-31-11-135 cookbooks]# chef-client -zr "recipe[test-cookbook::test-recipe]"
[2023-07-27T19:51:59+00:00] WARN: No config file found or specified on command line. Using command line options instead.
Chef Infra Client, version 18.2.7
Patents: https://www.chef.io/patents
Infra Phase starting
Resolving cookbooks for run list: ["test-cookbook::test-recipe"]
Synchronizing cookbooks:

- test-cookbook (0.1.0)
  Installing cookbook gem dependencies:
  Compiling cookbooks...
  Loading Chef InSpec profile files:
  Loading Chef InSpec input files:
  Loading Chef InSpec waiver files:
  Converging 0 resources

Running handlers:
Running handlers complete
Infra Phase complete, 0/0 resources updated in 02 seconds

Trying to create a file